# Why does sizeof(*node) give the size of the structure and not size of the pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sizeof

In the below code:

```
typedef struct{int data1; int data2} node;
node n1;
node* n2;

sizeof(n1) returns 8 // size of the struct node
sizeof(n2) returns 4 // since n2 is a pointer it returns the size of the pointer
sizeof(*n2) returns 8 // HOW DOES THIS WORK ?
```

How does sizeof actually work ? In the above case *n2 boils down to providing the address of where n2 is pointing. n2 in this case is still a dangling pointer as we have neither allocated memory nor are we pointing it to some valid address. How does it give the size of the structure correctly ?

Comment: "*n2 boils down to providing the address of where n2 is pointing" is incorrect.  `n2` is a pointer to a node, the value of `n2` is the address of a node, and `*n2` is a node.

Comment: As per comment above. `*n2` refers to what `n2` points at, not "the address of where n2 is pointing". In fact the value of `n2` itself is "the address of where n2 is pointing", because `n2` is a pointer.

Comment: It is sometimes helpful to write `sizeof *n2` to remind yourself that `sizeof` is an operator, and not a function.  Also, it is good style.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Any particular reason why it is good style ? Why is it better than saying sizeof(struct node). Hardly any book/website recommends this style. So am a bit puzzled.

Comment: @vikasm.  Consider the two assignments: `x = malloc( N * sizeof *x )` and `x = malloc( N * sizeof( struct foo ))`.  In the first, you know that enough space is allocated to store N objects in x.  In the second, you mush look elsewhere to verify the type of x.  Worse, if the declaration of x changes and x becomes a different type ( more likely with basic integer types), the second assignment becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

You need to understand two things:

First, what's the type of `*n2`? The type of `n2` is a pointer to `node`, so the type of `*n2` is `node`.

Second, you are right `n2` is a danging pointer, it doesn't point to a valid place, but the magic of `sizeof` is, it's a **compile time operator** (except when the operand is a C99 variable length array), `sizeof(*n2)` is evaluated as the same as `sizeof(node)` in compilation time.

Comment: Good with emphasizing compile time operator.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can read `*n2` as "the thing that n2 is pointing at".

The thing that n2 is pointing at is a node, and the sizeof a node is 8.   Simple as that...
it doesn't matter whether it's been allocated or not: the type of the thing that n2 is pointing at is a node, and the size of a node is 8.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `*n2`, where `n2` is defined as `node* n2` you are basically telling it to *read the data at the address* `n2` as if it had the type `node`.

It does not matter what is written on that address. Consider adding these lines to your example:

```
void *n3 = n2; // copies the address, but no information about the data there
int *n4 = (int *)n3; // again, copies the address

sizeof(*n4) returns sizeof(int)
```

So basically, to summarize, if you have:

```
X* a;
sizeof(a); // will always return 4, the size of a pointer
sizeof(*a); // will always return sizeof(X), no matter if the address is set.
```